# "И" между неоднородными определениями

Tags: согласование, определения, однородные-члены

В одной организации есть название отдела "Отдел идеологической работы, культуры и по делам молодёжи".

Грамотно ли оно составлено? Раз там стоит "и", то определения считаются однородными. Но они ведь даже отвечают на разные вопросы и, мне кажется, однородными не являются. А потому и "и" там не к месту, и всё определение составлено неверно.

Comment: Грамотно ли оно составлено? Да, но не изящно. Не на красоту ориентированная фраза. Однако, если сейчас здесь поставить задачу слепить «из того что было», она бы не имела решения более приемлемого.

Comment: В духе времени было бы "и молодёжной политики".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Отдел идеологической работы, культуры и молодежной политики** - этот (уже предложенный) вариант был бы наилучшим.

**Несогласованные определения**  обычно используются для описания внешних признаков предмета,  это набор различных признаков (а не раскрытие темы одного признака, как для согласованных определений). Поэтому вопрос об однородности/неоднородности таких определений обычно не ставится:  общей темой  здесь является именно описание, что по оформлению сближает их с однородными согласованными определениями. Несогласованные определения **разделяются запятой, а также соединяются союзом И.**

В приведенном примере в названии отражены различные вопросы, которыми занимается отдел. С точки зрения грамматики, это несогласованные определения, которые разделяются запятой и имеют замыкающий союз И, **но фраза при этом кажется некорректной**.

Дело в том, что здесь присутствует **грамматическая неоднородность** - разные падежи и предложное управление только для последнего определения. Если эту неоднородность исключить, то всё придет в норму (в конце концов, идеология и культура - это тоже не одна и та же тема, но в этом случае вопрос о корректности не возникает).

Answer (score -1):

Ну, вынужден признать, что по современным меркам - достаточно грамотно.

В советской традиции подобные названия были не редкостью, само существование подобных названий исключало все вопросы относительно грамотности. Видимо, времена, когда идеология командует филологией, возвращаются, как и многое из того времени.

Впрочем, в данном случае я не вижу больших стилистических, тем более - грамматических, нарушений. Да, тяжеловесно, но не более. Определения тут несогласованные (если вообще считать определениями эти по сути названия), поэтому вопрос об однородности через то, на какие вопросы они отвечают, не решается. Впрочем, отдел - "Какой?" и тут универсально. Через "И" тоже (*"шел студент в полдевятого, в пальто, в дождливый день и в университет"*), да и разве что-то изменится, если это "И" заменить на запятую?

Но главное, пожалуй, то, что по-другому-то и не скажешь. Если есть возможность сказать про три отдела "Идеологической работы", "Культуры" и "По делам молодёжи", почему нельзя сказать теми же словами про один?